# Is there a way to get libusb to behave in real time?

Tags: linux-kernel, usb, real-time

I recently applied the rt patch to my kernel in an attempt to lower the worst-case latency of sending messages over USB. Unfortunately I have seen no improvement in the worst-case over the unpatched kernel. Is there a patch I need for libusb, or even another way to communicate over USB to take advantage of the RT kernel to lower the worst-case latency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the most part the `RT kernel` will make subtle changes to insure your `frame time` is not over run.

Even then it is generally considered that the difference is very small, its more of a "if you aren't quite there, this might tip you over" adjustment.

If your USB performance is not good enough for what you are doing, you could try to reduce the number of devices connected to your system to free up additional hardware resources.

Or perhaps a faster version of USB.

As far as I know there isn't a means you could directly impact how fast your usb latency is unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Unfortunately I don't have the option of using a faster version of USB.

Comment: Yeah, I felt kind of mean spirited even mentioning it, as I'm sure you would be using it if it was an option, but for the sake of completeness i figured I would throw it in there. Another thing i would say is, Depending on your hardware, I've managed to get some decent tips/tricks out of manufacturers for Realtime performance issues, as far as `bios` settings. Sometimes some fairly innocent looking bios settings can be the difference between hitting your mark and missing it.